# Смена размера всех шрифтов

Tags: android, kotlin

В dimens.xml указываю размеры.

Необходимо:

- либо автоматически везде менять font size в приложении в зависимости от настроек размера шрифта/дисплей в самом телефоне
- либо в настройках приложения сделать ручную смену font size.

Создание dimens-hdpi и т.д. не помогает. Это работает, когда базовое разрешение самого экрана другое, а нужно в зависимости от Выставленных в настройках Андроид смартфона или просто сделать кнопку увеличения font size.

Comment: scaled pixel? sp

Comment: В dimens.xml значения установлены в SP, но размер шрифта не меняется.